# ZSTD support for GDAL GeoTIFFs with UbuntuGIS

Tags: geotiff-tiff, ubuntugis

I have some GeoTIFFs that are compressed with the ZSTD standard. I'm trying to serve those on a VM that has UbuntuGIS installed via the UbuntuGIS PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable on a base Ubuntu 18.04 image. The GDAL version on that PPA is 3.0.4.

When I try to `gdal.OpenEx` this file on the VM I get a `ERROR 1: Cannot open TIFF file due to missing codec.` error because I am missing the ZSTD codec I assume.

Is there a way to add ZSTD support for GDAL in UbuntuGIS? Perhaps through an `apt install` that I'm missing?

Comment: I see two close votes and a downvote. Am I asking the wrong question or in the wrong place?

Comment: No you're in the right place. Don't know about the down vote, but the one of the close votes (mine, now retracted) was because the Q. didn't contain enough information.  It's not what I thought (ZSTD requires GDAL > 2.3 so that's not the issue) but I'll have a look at the UbuntuGIS build to see if anything is obviously missing.

Comment: It seems that GDAL is at least built with ZSTD support https://launchpadlibrarian.net/468243097/buildlog_ubuntu-bionic-amd64.gdal_3.0.4+dfsg-1~bionic0_BUILDING.txt.gz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [GDAL GeoTIFF](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options) driver page:

> ZSTD is available since GDAL 2.3 when using internal libtiff and if
>   GDAL built against libzstd >=1.0, **or if built against external libtiff with zstd support**.

The DebianGIS and downstream UbuntuGIS packages are built against an external libtiff which *doesn't* have ZSTD support. From a [mailing list discussion](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu@lists.osgeo.org/msg01611.html) between a GDAL developer and UbuntuGIS maintainer:

> > From what I see in https://salsa.debian.org/debian-gis-team/gdal/blob/master/debian/rules, Debian builds GDAL against external/system libtiff, right ?
>
> Correct, because we want a single package for tiff security updates.
>
> > If so, libtiff must be built itself against libzstd, but I don't see it mentionned as a dependency of libtiff in https://packages.debian.org/sid/libtiff-dev
>
> tiff (4.0.9+git181026-1) adds support for zstd according to the
>   changelog.
>
> bionic has 4.0.9-5 which lacks this change.

I don't know of any other PPAs that provide GDAL (let alone with ZSTD support).
One option you have is to install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and create a conda environment with GDAL. I don't know if the default conda channel GDAL build includes ZSTD support, but the conda-forge channel GDAL does.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ conda create -n gdal_with_zstd -c conda-forge gdal=3 any other packages you need

$ conda activate gdal_with_zstd

$ gdalinfo test.tif | grep COMPRESSION
    COMPRESSION=ZSTD
```